# Implement CreateProcess using fork and exec

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, exec, createprocess

I am just starting out in Operating Systems and I have this assignment.

**Problem Description**

Different OS have different system calls/APIs which vary in creating new processes and running of executables. Ignore the fact that threads can be created to simplify this question. In Windows, the basic process creation API is CreateProcess. It is an API rather than a system call because Windows can be thought of as a kind of micro-kernel architecture There are two versions of CreateProcess, for our purposes we will not distinguish them, and will just use CreateProcessA (Ansi version).

For this question, we will only compare the following parameters:

```
  LPCSTR                lpApplicationName,

  LPSTR                 lpCommandLine,

  LPVOID                lpEnvironment
```

Suppose we have a simplified CreateProcess API with only: CreateProcessEasy(lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, lpEnvironment).

Sketch using pseudocode how to implement Windows code using CreateProcessSimple with Unix APIs (fork and exec family).

Along the way of doing, I met a few problems of not really understanding the flags, especially if excluding some of them means that I have to make assumptions. Can anyone comment on my understanding based on my attempt?

**Attempt**

```
BOOL CreateProcessEasy(lpApplicationName,lpCommandLine,lpEnvironment) {

    pid_t pid;
    /* fork a child process */
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) { /* error occurred */ 
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed"); 
        return 0; 
    }
    else if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
        if (lpApplicationName==NULL) {
            path = Filter out the path required to be passed into execve from lpCommandLine
            if (path==NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "No path found");
                return 0; 
            } else {
                execve(path,lpCommandLine,lpEnvironment);
                return 1;           
            }

        } 
        if (lpCommandLine==NULL) {
            if (lpApplicationName not found in current directory) {
                fprintf(stderr, "File not found");
                return 0; 
            } else {
                execve(lpApplicationName,NULL,lpEnvironment);
                return 1;
            }

        } 

        return 1;
    } else {/* parent process */
        /* parent will wait for the child to complete */
        wait(pid);
        printf("Child Complete");
        return 1;
    }
}
```